# How to extract a color channel from array of images in python

Tags: python, numpy, tensor

I have a tensor of 10 samples, each which contain 10 time-series 20x20x3 RGB images which I would like to extract the green color channel

The images are stored in an array of arrays called images

For example:

```
images[0][0][:,:,1]
```

returns back the green channel for for one image in one sample.

However, when I try to use the command:

```
images[0][:][:,:,1]
```

I receive the error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

How would I generalize my first line of code to pull all of the green channel images from the 1st sample?

Shapes of the data:

```
images.shape
(10,)

images[0].shape
(10,)

images[0][0].shape
(20,20,3)
```

Here is a sample of the data. The data are images which were extrated from a .mat file so it is stored as an array of arrays, with a sample shown below:

```
images
array([[array([[[41,  0,  0],
    [43,  0,  0],
    [45,  0,  0],
    ...,
    [18,  0,  0],
    [ 5,  0,  0],
    [ 0,  0,  0]],

   [[45,  0,  0],
    [50,  0,  0],
    [49,  0,  0],
    ...,
    [ 3,  0,  0],
    [ 0,  0,  0],
    [ 0,  0,  0]],

   [[49,  0,  0],
    [49,  0,  0],
    [48,  0,  0],
    ...,
    [ 0,  0,  0],
    [ 0,  0,  0],
    [ 0,  0,  0]],

   ...,

   [[16,  0,  0],
    [ 5,  0,  0],
    [ 1,  0,  0],
    ...,
    [ 0,  0,  0],
    [ 0,  0,  0],
    [ 0,  0,  0]],

   [[ 3,  0,  0],
    [ 1,  0,  0],
    [ 0,  0,  0],
    ...,
    [ 0,  0,  0],
    [ 0,  0,  0],
    [ 0,  0,  0]],

   [[ 0,  0,  0],
    [ 0,  0,  0],
    [ 0,  0,  0],
    ...,
    [ 0,  0,  0],
    [ 0,  0,  0],
    [ 0,  0,  0]]], dtype=uint8),
    array([[[87,  0,  0],
    [92,  0,  0],
    [86,  0,  0],
    ...,
    [33,  0,  0],
    [51,  0,  0],
    [60,  0,  0]],

   [[90,  0,  0],
    [88,  0,  0],
    [79,  0,  0],
    ...,
    [11,  0,  0],
    [21,  0,  0],
    [41,  0,  0]],

   [[89,  0,  0],
    [82,  0,  0],
    [62,  0,  0],
    ...,
    [12,  0,  0],
    [ 4,  0,  0],
    [16,  0,  0]],

   ...,

   [[77,  0,  0],
    [77,  0,  0],
    [76,  0,  0],
    ...,
    [48,  0,  0],
    [44,  0,  0],
    [42,  0,  0]],

   [[88,  0,  0],
    [85,  0,  0],
    [85,  0,  0],
    ...,
    [54,  0,  0],
    [53,  0,  0],
    [51,  0,  0]],

   [[89,  0,  0],
    [89,  0,  0],
    [88,  0,  0],
    ...,
    [55,  0,  0],
    [54,  0,  0],
    [53,  0,  0]]], dtype=uint8),
```

Comment: can you include `images.shape` ?

Comment: The original images came from a .mat file, so it is an array of arrays. images.shape returns back (10,) and images[0].shape returns back (10,) as well, however images[0][0].shape will show (20,20,3). The answer Julien provided using list comprehension worked for me though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting numpy arrays of arrays into one whole numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192603/converting-numpy-arrays-of-arrays-into-one-whole-numpy-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
green_0 = [i[:,:,1] for i in images[0]]
all_greens = [[i[:,:,1] for i in ims] for ims in images]
```

but if `images` is already a numpy array, you can simply do `images[0,:,:,:,1]` and `images[:,:,:,:,1]`

Comment: Great, worked like a charm. I used np.concatenate to turn the list back into an array and used np.reshape to make each sample 10x20x20 then converted each back to a tensor. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `images` is a NumPy `ndarray` with the following dimensions:

```
images[sample_dim, time_dim, width, height, color]
```

you could simply resort to a single slicing operation, e.g.:

```
images[:, :, :, :, 1]
```

to get only green across your dataset.

---

What you have been doing, i.e.:

```
images[0][0][:, :, 1]
```

could be rewritten more cleanly and efficiently as:

```
images[0, 0, :, :, 1]
```

---

To understand why `images[0][0][:, :, 1]` does work and `images[0][:][:, :, 1]` does not, I suggest you to take a look at the shapes of `images[0][0]` and `images[0][:]`, which are the object you are trying to slice the final time with `[:, :, 1]`

---

If `images` is not a single multidimensional array, you could just call `np.array()` constructor on nested lists and it should convert it to a proper `ndarray`.

---

Instead, if your input is a NumPy array of `object`s, where each object is also a NumPy array, [the most efficient approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64099096/5218354) is:

```
np.array(images.tolist())
```

Comment: The data is an ndarray, however it is an array of arrays. I updated my question with an example of the data.

Comment: @BenCWang See update, but basically `np.array()` should convert `images` to a proper single multidimensional array.

Comment: you touched an on interested idea. I gave it a shot, and tried to nest np.array(np.array(images)) but it wasn't converting the array to a single array. I looked it up and found this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192603/converting-numpy-arrays-of-arrays-into-one-whole-numpy-array which shows that np.concatenate does the trick. It also requires is a np.reshape to get back to the correct dimensions, but it achieves the same results as the list comp answer @Julien gave.

Comment: @BenCWang If you provide a [minimal reproducible example](/help/mcve) it is probably the best approach. Right now I am only guessing what `images` is. But I would recommend using `np.concatenate()` sparingly as this is often less efficient than alternatives.

Comment: @BenCWang See updates. Instead of `np.array(np.array(images))` you should probably do `np.array(images.tolist())`, which is far more efficient than `np.concatenate(images).reshape(...)`.