# split 1d np array into 3d array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following array:

```
x_train.shape
(7201,)

x_train
array([array([[0.01709922],
       [0.01946028],
       [0.01317027],
       [0.01228488],
       [0.01372365],
       [0.02148931],
       [0.01127036],
       [0.01887001],
       [0.01468282],
       [0.01235866]], dtype=float32),
       array([[0.01269068],
       [0.01193441],
       [0.01077232],
       [0.01219265],
       [0.02014277],
       [0.01250623],
       [0.01759726],
       [0.01145482],
       [0.00204748],
       [0.00372604]], dtype=float32),
       array([[0.01660118],
       [0.01931271],
       [0.02100972],
       [0.0167303 ],
       [0.02126796],
       [0.01245089],
       [0.00612399],
       [0.01128881],
       [0.01344696],
       [0.01422168]], dtype=float32),
       ...,
```

I want to transform it into the shape (X,10,1).

How can i do this in the first place, whats an efficient way to do this?

Comment: another dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50971123/converty-numpy-array-of-arrays-to-2d-array

Comment: Do you understand why it is a 1d object dtype array in the first place?  Are the arrays all the same shape?  A quick count suggested that one has 11 rows.  If they do match, `np.stack(x_train)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you instantiate a numpy array using `np.array`, it will detect if the inputs comprise a regularly shaped array, and if so, it will give you a multi-dimensional array automatically.

If you have somehow managed to end up with an array of objects despite it being regularly shaped, you could convert it to a list and try again, for example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros(3, dtype=object)

x[0] = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4]])
x[1] = np.array([[5],[6],[7],[8]])
x[2] = np.array([[9],[10],[11],[12]])

print(x.shape, x.dtype)  # prints (3,) object                                                                                               

y = np.array(list(x))

print(y.shape, y.dtype) )  # prints (3, 4, 1) int64
```

If this fails (giving you a warning about ragged sequences) and gives you back another object array, then your array was not in fact regularly shaped - in which case, check the number of elements in each of the subarrays.  You will see this if you remove one of the elements in the above test code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however this didnt work for me.
i found this answer which worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35193026/8055893