# How to convert a list to an 1D array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Trying to convert a list to 1D array and that list contain arrays like this

from

```
[array([1145,  330, 1205,  364], dtype=int64),
 array([1213,  330, 1247,  364], dtype=int64),
 array([ 883,  377, 1025,  412], dtype=int64),
 array([1038,  377, 1071,  404], dtype=int64),
 array([1085,  377, 1195,  405], dtype=int64),
 array([1210,  377, 1234,  405], dtype=int64)]
```

Required

```
array([array([1145,  330, 1205,  364], dtype=int64),
       array([[1213,  330, 1247,  364], dtype=int64),
       array([883,  377, 1025,  412], dtype=int64),
       array([1038,  377, 1071,  404], dtype=int64),
       array([1085,  377, 1195,  405], dtype=int64),
       array([1085,  377, 1195,  405], dtype=int64), dtype=object))
```

tried this code but getting 2D array but need 1D array like above

```
art = []
for i in boxs:
    art.append(np.array(i, dtype=np.int64))
new_ary = np.array(art)
new_ary
```

Comment: Are you sure you need such an array? Why is it any better than the list?

Comment: to make a 1d object array from arrays that are all the same size, you have to **start** with a 1d object array, and fill it.  `np.array` won't work..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73459489/901925 shows how to do this

Comment: Thanks for the replay @hpaulj my requirement is 1D array with all these element array([1145,  330, 1205,  364], dtype=int64 like above

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little ambiguous. Your input is already a 2D and in

```
for i in boxs:
    art.append(np.array(i, dtype=np.int64))
```

`i` represents a list in each iteration. So, You are appending a list each time in `art`.

You can try `new_ary = new_ary.flatten()`. It will give you

```
[1145  330 1205  364 1213  330 1247  364  883  377 1025  412 1038  377 1071  404 1085  377 1195  405 1210  377 1234  405]
```

Otherwise, provide an output to clarify your question.

Comment: You are right. the actual input is '[1145,  330, 1205,  364],
 [1213,  330, 1247,  364], [ 883,  377, 1025,  412], [1038,  377, 1071,  404], [1085,  377, 1195,  405], [1210,  377, 1234,  405]' and required the above 1D array. So i did some processing i am able to get an 2D array but the requirement is an 1D array.

Comment: please do vote or accept the answer so others find it correct.

Answer (score 0):

While you are changing the list of arrays to an array of arrays with `dtype=object`, the value in the array is still int.

```
np.array(a, dtype=object)
array([[1145, 330, 1205, 364],
       [1213, 330, 1247, 364],
       [883, 377, 1025, 412],
       [1038, 377, 1071, 404],
       [1085, 377, 1195, 405],
       [1210, 377, 1234, 405]], dtype=object)

type(np.array(a, dtype=object)[0][0])
Out[151]: int
```

### Update

If you want to flatten the 2D array to a 1D array, you can use `np.ravel`

```
np.ravel(a)
array([1145,  330, 1205,  364, 1213,  330, 1247,  364,  883,  377, 1025,
        412, 1038,  377, 1071,  404, 1085,  377, 1195,  405, 1210,  377,
       1234,  405], dtype=int64)
```

Or let's say you want a 1D list, you can first do `map` to convert the array to list and then do `reduce`

```
from functools import reduce

mylist = list(map(list, a))

print(reduce((lambda x, y: x+y) , mylist))
[1145, 330, 1205, 364, 1213, 330, 1247, 364, 883, 377, 1025, 412, 1038, 377, 1071, 404, 1085, 377, 1195, 405, 1210, 377, 1234, 405]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the output you are getting as like mine its a 2D array but my requirement is 1D array as like above Required

Comment: Please excuse my not understanding, but your post's desired output is still a 2D array. So you want a 1D array or a 1D list?

Comment: Thanks for the replay @Kevin Choon Liang Yew, Forget about the list for my reference i stored into a list my requirement is 1D array with all these element array([1145, 330, 1205, 364], dtype=int64 like above, I stored into a list because I thought I can convert that list into a python array.

Comment: Then, in this case, it's better you create a list with lists, instead of a list with arrays. It will save you more time and memory. The dtype itself will be there when you have a list of integers.

Comment: No i cant do like that, is there any way that i can append the items from a list to an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

use `.reshape(-1)` on the individual arrays inside that list.